# PDFsharp one Word in Bold

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I need to find a way where I can put one word in bold.

I have a long text and need some words in bold.

```
File.WriteAllText("Vertrag/vertrag.txt", File.ReadAllText("Vertrag/vertrag.txt").Replace("Verstragsgegenstand",  new XFont("Verdana"mbox 7m XFontStyle.Bold) "BoldWord");
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe "Verstragsgegenstand" (sic) cannot be found in the text file. The `String.Replace` approach will not work even when searching for "Vertragsgegenstand".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use chunck

```
string path = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(400, 300);
Document doc = new Document(r);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "/Blocks.pdf",     FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("A chunk represents an isolated string. ");
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    doc.Add(c1);
}
```

More details in http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/82/itextsharp-adding-text-with-chunks-phrases-and-paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

With PDFsharp you have to split your text and make separate calls to `DrawString` for normal and bold text.

I'd recommend using MigraDoc. You still have to split the text and use `AddFormattedText` for the bold words, but you get line breaks and page breaks automatically.

The approach shown in your question (using `String.Replace`) will not work.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocHelloWorld-sample.ashx